# How do I remove the * from a password field in a web2py password field. I only need it blank

Tags: python-2.7, web2py

I have a password field that needs to be changes every once in a while. I have a regular:

`form = SQLFORM(db.table, id)`

I want to simply print the form to the view but with the following change:
How do I stop Web2py from showing the * symbols and just show nothing at all so the user has to enter the new data every time any editing to the form occurs.

Currently it shows ****** with the values of ****** in html.

Do I really need to make a customer view for this issue?
Users are getting confused about the form thinking it still contains a working password when it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the widget of the password field:

```
db.mytable.password.widget = lambda f, v: SQLFORM.widgets.password.widget(f, v, _value='')
```

This can also be done in the table definition:

```
db.define_table('mytable',
    ...,
    Field('password', 'password',
          widget=lambda f, v: SQLFORM.widgets.password.widget(f, v, _value='')),
    ...)
```

If you want to make this change for all password fields in all applications, you can instead monkey patch the `sqlhtml` module:

```
from gluon import sqlhtml
sqlhtml.DEFAULT_PASSWORD_DISPLAY = ''
```